# Conditional clause (then)

Tags: grammar, conditional-constructions

In this first instance the main clause only stands alone if you  omit (then).

But in the other example it clearly has a main clause. So would this be classed as an embedded main clause as it only works as a independent clause if it's adjusted and or if it's joined with a dependent clause.

If I have enough money, **then I will buy a new car.**

If it rains, **the picnic will be cancelled.**

The picnic will be cancelled if it rains.

Answer (score 1):

The use of **then** is optional, and it does not affect the syntax of the sentence. The main clause is still *(then)* ***I will buy a new car.***

To put this another way, here are several variations of the main clause:

> Then, I will buy a new car.
>   I will then buy a new car.
>   I will buy a new car then.

The first example is the most literal use of the text you provided, simply with some punctuation that makes it stand completely on its own.