# “If” in dependent clause, and “then” in independent

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, difference

> If it’s not raining outside, I’ll go to the park.

> If it’s not raining outside, **then** I will go to the park.

> If I could speak English, I would go to London.

> If could speak English, **then** I would go to London.

What’s the difference in meaning between those independent clauses? Is “then” unnecessary to use, or does it convey a different meaning here?

Comment: There is no difference in meaning. If the 'if' clause was quite a long one, adding _then_ might help to make the meaning clearer; otherwise it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional clause (then).](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/169526/conditional-clause-then) As pointed out there, *The use of "then" is optional, and **it does not affect the syntax** of the sentence.* Nor does it affect the meaning, as @KateBunting says here.